# History query to find when number of relations became non-zero

Tags: mysql

I have a table of employees that indicates who is each employee's manager. As time goes on and employee data changes, more records are added, but the old data is preserved, so that we can know the state of any employee at any point in time.

The table has data like this (along with many, many, more columns):

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | person_id | name   | manager_id | creation_date       | something_else |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | 1         | Alice  | 1000       | 2014-05-08 04:43:50 | A              |
| 2  | 2         | Bob    | 1001       | 2014-05-09 04:43:50 | A              |
| 3  | 2         | Bob    | 1001       | 2014-05-10 04:43:50 | B              |
| 4  | 2         | Bob    | 1          | 2014-05-11 04:43:50 | B              |
| 5  | 3         | Carl   | 1001       | 2015-05-11 04:43:50 | B              |
| 6  | 3         | Carl   | 1          | 2016-05-11 04:43:50 | B              |
| 7  | 3         | Carl   | 1          | 2017-05-11 04:43:50 | D              |
| 8  | 3         | Carl   | 1002       | 2018-05-11 04:43:50 | B              |
| 9  | 2         | Bob    | 1002       | 2018-05-11 04:43:50 | B              |
| 10 | 4         | Diane  | 1          | 2019-05-11 04:43:50 | C              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

From this we can infer that Alice became Bob's supervisor on May 11, 2014. Also, Alice became Carl's boss in 2016, then became no one's boss in 2018, and became Diane's boss in 2019.

I need to answer the question "When did Alice most recently become a manager?" where in this case manager means having someone report to her. (The `something_else` column is to demonstrate that profile records can be added for changes that have nothing to do with the org hierarchy.)

For a sense of scale, the `profiles` table in my database has more than 8 million records.

I have a query that is an imperfect tool to help me answer that question. The following query answers the question "how many direct reports does Alice have at a given moment?"

```
SELECT `profiles`.`person_id`
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(`id`) AS `id`
    FROM (
        SELECT `id`, `creation_date`, `person_id`
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT(`person_id`) AS `person_id` 
                FROM `profiles` WHERE `manager_id` = <manager id> 
                                AND `creation_date` <= "<time>"                     
        ) AS `reportingIds`
        JOIN `profiles` USING (`person_id`)
    ) AS `allDirectProfiles`
    WHERE `creation_date` < "<time>" GROUP BY `person_id`
) AS `profilesOnDate`
JOIN `profiles` USING (`id`)
WHERE `manager_id` = <manager id>;
```

To dissect that a bit, it's a three-layer query, where the first layer gets a list of everyone who has ever had Alice as a boss up to the specified date. The next layer takes that list and finds the profile record for each person that was relevant on the specified date, then the final join eliminates the records that have the wrong boss.

This query works, and usually well enough, but there are cases where Alice may have had hundreds of direct reports over the course of her career, and many of those workers could have hundreds of records in the database. When things get bad, this query falls off the cliff pretty fast, to where it can take several seconds just to test a particular point in time. (Currently I test each point in time where Alice's record changes.)

My question has three tiers:

1. Maximum joy: Is there a way to write a query that answers "when
   did the number of Alice's direct reports go from zero to non-zero
   (and also, non-zero to zero)? I think the short answer to this
   question is "no", but I would love to be wrong.
2. Light bulb: The query above answers "how many direct
   reports does Alice have at a given moment?" All I actually need to
   know is "Does Alice have *any* reports at a given moment?" Does
   reframing the question suggest an optimization?
3. Deep gratitude: Failing both of the above, is there a way to make this query more
   efficient? Part of my brain is trying to convince me that I could
   replace at least one subquery with a join, but the part of my brain
   that has to do the actual work hasn't figured out how.

Final note: Having punted on calculating this in real time, I am using this query to build a separate table to track these transitions, and the table will be updated whenever a new profile record is added. So, by the time you answer this, I likely will have burned many cpu hours to render it moot. But I think I can learn a lot from your answers, and if there is a viable real-time option, That would make my day.

Comment: According to your sample data, does it mean that `Bob` was directly reporting to `Alice` from `2014-05-11` until `2018-05-10`? Right before `Bob` was reassigned to a different `manager_id` on the ` 2018-05-11`?

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not an image) output from `show create table profiles;`

Comment: @FaNo_FN yes, that is correct. Bob is assumed to report to Alice until a new record says otherwise.

Comment: @Jerry if you get a chance to try my answer, let me know how it does

Comment: @ysth - that is a massively simplified version of the table almost to the point of being a fiction, but there's no magic to it. If you are curious about indexes then yes, the relevant columns are indexed.

Comment: too many indexes can sometimes be worse than too few :)

Comment: Yeah, I hear you son that. For this table we have another smaller table to join on that is basically a home-brew index for some of the columns.

Comment: Is this anything close to [Maximum Joy](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c688612e4381654357e97dff2565f403)?

Comment: Window functions! I know what I'll be reading up on today. I'll be testing your solution in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Without the full set of data, it's hard to know what will be most efficient.  But here's what I'd try:

```
select max(p1.creation_date)
from profiles p1
where
    p1.manager_id=1
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from profiles p2
        where
            p2.manager_id=p1.manager_id
            and p2.creation_date < p1.creation_date
            and not exists (
                select 1
                from profiles p3
                where
                    p3.person_id=p2.person_id
                    and p3.creation_date between p2.creation_date and p1.creation_date
                    and p3.manager_id <> p2.manager_id
            )
    )
```

In English, look for the maximum of all the times where Alice was assigned as a manager, when for that time she had no previous assignments as a manager for someone who wasn't reassigned in the interim.

This would benefit from indexes on (manager_id,creation_date) and on (person_id,creation_date,manager_id)

Comment: This looks almost magic; I will test it in the morning and let you know the result.